# design of online student grade result

Tags: php, sql

I am writing my project on online student result which will compute the grade         point,average grade point and cummulative grade point.the output required is:

```
Name: Shakira Abdullahi
Adm.No: 096784657    
Department: Information Technology
Semester: 1st semester
Level: 200

Course title                     Course code    Course unit    score     Grade
Computer programming II            Csc 201        3             45        D
Introduction to file procesing     Csc 204        2             57        C
Introduction to the internet       Int 201        3             34        F
Linear algebra II                  Mth 205        2             60        B
Real Analysis I                    Mth 207        3             76        A
Numeric Analysis                   Mth 209        2             42        E
Nigerian people and culture        Gst 201        2             80        A

Units this session:17
Units to date:35
G.P this session:47
G.P.A last session:3.43
G.P.A to date:2.87
Remarks: To repeat Int 201

Examination grading
Score(%)    grade   Grade points     
70-100        A       5
60-69         B       4
50-59         C       3
45-49         D       2
40-44         E       1
0-39          F       0
```

Explanation:

- `Units this session`: total course units this session
- `Units to date`: cumulative of each session units up-to this session
- `G.P this session`: sum(each course(grade point  x unit) )
- `G.P to date`: cumulative of each session G.P up-to this session
- `G.P.A last session`: Average G.P last session
- `G.P.A to date`: Average G.P to date.
- `level`: we have up to 4 levels: 100, 200, 300 and 400

Also what is required by the user before having access to the result are:
    Name, Adm.No, Department, semester and session.
    the session is in form of years e.g 2010-2011.

So please, how do I go about this project?  My questions are:

- Can I maintain a table for this?
- How do I go about the query?

Comment: Your question[s] are too broad for our QA format.  You should limit your posts to one question per post.  Additionally, please know that people will not write your project for you...  You'll have to demonstrate that you have tried as well...

Comment: Why not start the project and when/if you come across a problem, come and post it here with all the details including perhaps code samples of things you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a database with different tables linking to a master table with students.

This is the structure of tables I would create:

- student
- courses
- scores
- grading

Within each of these I would create the required columns.

**Student Table**

Within the student table create a columns for the following:

- ID (Primary, INT, 11, autoincrement)
- Name (Varchar, 256)
- AdmNo (INT, 11)
- Department (Varchar, 256)
- Semester (Could be an ID with corresponding values or a Varchar with a max of 256 characters)
- Level (INT, 11)
- SessionUnits (INT, 11)
- DateUnits (INT, 11)
- ThisGP (INT,11)
- LastGPA (Float)
- TDGPA (Float)
- Remarks (Varchar, 256)

**Courses**

- ID (Primary, INT, 11, autoincrement)
- Name (Varchar, 256)
- CourseCode (Varchar, 256)

**Scores**

- ID (Primary, INT, 11, autoincrement)
- StudentID (ID, 11)
- CourseID (ID, 11)
- Score (ID, 11)
- CourseUnit (ID,11)
- Grade (Varchar, 256)

**Grading**

- ScoreMinPercent (INT,11)
- ScoreMaxPercent (INT,11)
- Grade (Varchar, 256)
- GradePoints (INT, 11)

The SQL with the values included would be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `AdmNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Department` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `Semester` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `Level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SessionUnits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateUnits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ThisGP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastGPA` float NOT NULL,
  `TDGPA` float NOT NULL,
  `Remarks` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `student` (`ID`, `Name`, `AdmNo`, `Department`, `Semester`, `Level`, `SessionUnits`, `DateUnits`, `ThisGP`, `LastGPA`, `TDGPA`, `Remarks`) VALUES
(1, 'Shakira Abdullahi', 96784657, 'Information Technology', '1st semester', 200, 17, 35, 47, 3.43, 2.87, 'To repeat Int 201');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `CourseCode` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `courses` (`ID`, `Name`, `CourseCode`) VALUES
(1, 'Computer programming II', 'Csc 201'),
(2, 'Introduction to file procesing', 'Csc 204'),
(3, 'Introduction to the internet', 'Int 201'),
(4, 'Linear algebra II', 'Mth 205'),
(5, 'Real Analysis I', 'Mth 207'),
(6, 'Numeric Analysis', 'Mth 209'),
(7, 'Nigerian people and culture', 'Gst 201');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StudentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CourseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CourseUnit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Grade` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `scores` (`ID`, `StudentID`, `CourseID`, `Score`, `CourseUnit`, `Grade`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 45, 3, 'D'),
(2, 1, 2, 57, 2, 'C'),
(3, 1, 3, 34, 3, 'F'),
(4, 1, 4, 60, 2, 'B'),
(5, 1, 5, 76, 3, 'A'),
(6, 1, 6, 42, 2, 'E'),
(7, 1, 7, 80, 2, 'A');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grading` (
  `ScoreMinPercent` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ScoreMaxPercent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Grade` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `GradePoints` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ScoreMinPercent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77 ;

INSERT INTO `grading` (`ScoreMinPercent`, `ScoreMaxPercent`, `Grade`, `GradePoints`) VALUES
(40, 44, 'E', 1),
(45, 49, 'D', 2),
(50, 59, 'C', 3),
(60, 69, 'B', 4),
(70, 100, 'A', 5),
(71, 39, 'F', 0);
```

Comment: thanks you've given me an insight.

Comment: if this is helps you please up vote and accept it, thank you

Comment: +1 for me for the work... just one question: are u gandhi?